# Should google analytics snippet be inside <head>

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is it necessary to have google analytics snippet within  tag. Is this mandatory ?

I am trying to add google analytics dynamically on a side. The code that links the site to google analytics is separate.

If it is mandatory to have google analytics snippet within head, can we alter the DOM from javascript and append the scriptlet dynamically,By javascript ??

I tried these flows in local, without good outcome.

Comment: Put it at the end of your body tag to prevent it from interfering with the rest of your page loading.  There's no need to put it in your `<head>`  Google provides the script to dynamically load it into your head that you place at the end of your body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Code will work if you put it in the footer (or really anywhere else), insofar it is not "necessary" to have it in the head. However I can think of at last two reasons why you should put it in the head.

1. Account verification via the analytics e.g. with Google webmaster
   tools is not possible if the analytics code is in the wrong-ish
   location (however you can upload a verification file instead), and
   it might be that Analytics complains that your tracking code is not
   installed (cosmetic error, the code will still work).
2. If you use Universal Analytics the code snippet must be put
   before any calls to ga() (pageviews etc) - that's because the code
   snippets sets up the ga function that stores your analytics calls to
   an array (te analytics.js file that executes the tracking calls is
   loaded asynchronously, so it will not interfere with the rest of
   your page in any case).  If your code is in the head section you
   don't have to worry about that, if you put it in the body you have
   to make sure yourself that no tracking calls are lodged before the
   ga function is set up.